# How to cleanup cypress cy.intercept requests queue?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm testing several filters (they are on backend) for a dashboard consecutevely using spy function written in `before(() => {...})` block :

```
function aliasQuery(
  request: CyHttpMessages.IncomingHttpRequest,
  operationName: string,
): void {
  const { body } = request;
  if (body.operationName === operationName) {
    request.alias = operationName;
  }
}

export function spyOnGraphQL(operationName: string): void {
  cy.fixture('hosts').then(({ graphQLHostname }) => {
    cy.intercept(ApiMethods.Post, graphQLHostname, (request) => {
      aliasQuery(request, operationName);
    });
  });
}
```

Then inside `for` loop I use

```
cy.wait(`@${operationName}`).should(({response}) => {...})
```

to check filters one by one.

There's trouble though, after using every filter and getting results I need to reset all filters by sending another graphql request, this request's query name matches the filter's query name, so when `cy.wait` is called again it catches **reset filters** request which breaks everything.It  goes like this:

- Applying filter 1 (graphql request 1)
- Using `cy.wait`, it catches request 1
- Resetting filters (graphql request 2)
- Applying filter 2 (graphql request 3)
- Using `cy.wait`, it catches request 2  --> That's where the problems begin

Is there a way to clean up requests caught by `cy.intercept` before applying a new filter? Or at least distinguish reset request from filter request using request payload for instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `times` option to make sure your intercept only matches once and redefined it later when you are expecting the request. Example:

```js
cy.intercept({ url: /\/api\/.*\/path\/.*/, times: 1 }).as("fetchingMyData")
cy.wait("@fetchingMyData").then(() => { ... }) // the first wait


cy.intercept({ url: /\/api\/.*\/path\/.*/, times: 1 }).as("fetchingMyData2") // this resets the alias and the intercepted requests so that any request made before this point won't be considered.
cy.wait("@fetchingMyData2").then(() => { ... }) // the second wait
```

Have a look at the options in the docs for more info: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#routeMatcher-RouteMatcher

Answer (score 1):

There is an outstanding feature request for cypress asking for this to be added.
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/23192

For now I've found a workaround, it's a little clunky but it solves the issue for my use case.

I added this custom command, which will loop over the list of currently intercepted requests and call cy.wait() for any where the request has responseWaited is false.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('clearInterceptList', (interceptAlias) => {
  // clears the list of intercepted requests by waiting for each one
  // intercept alias should be in the form '@postExample' etc.
  cy.get(interceptAlias + '.all').then((browserRequests) => {
    for (let request of browserRequests) {
      if (request.responseWaited === false) {
        cy.wait(interceptAlias)
      }
    }
  })
})
```

The important thing is this would need to be called before the request is triggered again. So in your for loop it would be something like this:

```
1. Reset filters
2. cy.clearInterceptList(`@${operationName}`)
3. Apply new filter
4. cy.wait(`@${operationName}`).should(({response}) => {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to clean up the request queue, but I was able to use an extra callback to ignore some requests by giving them different alias.

```
function aliasQuery(
  request: CyHttpMessages.IncomingHttpRequest,
  operationName: string,
  callback?: TypeAliasQueryCallback,
): void {
  const { body } = request;

  if (body.operationName === operationName) {
    request.alias = operationName;

    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
      callback(request);
    }
  }
}

export function spyOnGraphQL(
  operationName: string,
  callback?: TypeAliasQueryCallback,
): void {
  cy.fixture('hosts').then(({ graphQLHostname }) => {
    cy.intercept(ApiMethods.Post, graphQLHostname, (request) => {
      aliasQuery(request, operationName, callback);
    });
  });
}

export function ignoreResetRequest(
  request: CyHttpMessages.IncomingHttpRequest,
): void {
  const { body } = request;

  // Checking if the filters are sent (resetting sends empty array)
  if (!body.variables.filter.and.length) {
    request.alias = 'ignored';
  }
}

spyOnGraphQL('some_operation_name', ignoreResetRequest);
```